# How go from one UI to another UI on Image button click event in juce introjucer?

Tags: juce

can you please tell me How go from one UI to another UI on Image button click event in juce introjucer?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to:

1.- Parent component must inherit from ButtonListener, and you must implement the buttonclicked method

```
void WindowComponent::buttonClicked (Button* activeButton) 
{
    if (activeButton == &someButton)
    {
        gotoOtherPage();
    }

}
```

2.- Your "UIs" i must suppose are components, if so just do something like:

```
component.setVisible(false), 
otherComponent.setVisible(true),
```

Or perhaps stash them in a TabbedComponent, hide the tabs or overlap some buttons and then just do:

```
tabbedComponent.setCurrentTabIndex(someIndex);
```

That should get you going, in case you need help to draw a button just do something like:

```
addAndMakeVisible (&someButton);
someButton.setBounds(...);
someButton.addListener(this);
```

Check out the doxygen docs, they are quite helpful.